# JsonConvert.SerializeObject() throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a program with multiple threads which share a collection. One thread is modifying the list, the other thread serializes the list and sends it off to a web service.
What I get from time to time is the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.'

In my real problem the list does not hold `int` but instances of domain models.
The error is obvious for me, but not the remedy. I wrote a small program to reproduce the issue:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // from System.ServiceModel.dll.
    var itemList = new SynchronizedCollection<int>();
    var updateThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            itemList.Add(itemList.Count);
        }
    });
    var serializeThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemList);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
    });

    updateThread.Start();
    serializeThread.Start();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You have to limit access to the list to one thread at a time, this can be done in multiple ways - one is to use a `System.Threading.Monitor`.

Comment: `One thread is modifying the list, the other thread serializes the list` this is not acceptable, and always will throw exception

Comment: What do you want to serialize, though? The contents of the whole collection, whatever they may happen to be at the time? As written you'd be doing a lot of redundant serializing of items that have already been sent. If that's really your intent, though, pick your poison: explicit `lock`s, making a copy of the collection before serializing (but that typically also needs a `lock`), or getting a collection that offers thread-safe enumeration (those are rare, but I recall there are some in the framework -- just not which ones).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I was hoping that `SynchronizedCollection` would be taking care of that. Locking works well, but I hoped to get around that.

Comment: Well, it *does* "take care of that", after a fashion -- `SynchronizedCollection.GetEnumerator()` takes a `lock` before it calls `.GetEnumerator()` on the underlying list. But, of course, this does *not* make the enumeration itself thread safe at all. The documentation really ought to mention that... (To be fair, a completely generic implementation could only offer thread-safe enumeration by locking the whole object during the entire duration of the enumeration, which is not any better than just locking yourself.)

Comment: Another option is to use an `ImmutableList` that you continuously replace (`itemList = itemList.Add(item)`). Enumerating those instances should be safe, and the immutable collections take care to share memory where appropriate. This still needs to be tested for acceptable performance.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert I was talking to a coworker and he came up with the same idea.

Comment: Switching to `ConcurrentBag` does seem to work too, but I really doubt this is the appropriate use case.

Comment: There you go, that's what I forgot. The concurrent collections offer thread-safe enumeration as well, with some pitfalls (`ConcurrentDictionary`'s enumeration is safe, but does not represent any actual point-in-time state of the dictionary). If you don't care about the order of items, `ConcurrentBag` may well be useful, but I agree it's not necessarily the most obvious choice for a collection just to get thread-safe enumeration.